# When we import a module do we have a method in Python?

Tags: python, methods, module

So the question is basically:

I have a module called `Fibo` that has, for example, a function called `fibonacci()` that calculates a Fibonacci sequence. Since I want to use this in my program, I have to do this:

```py
import Fibo

Fibo.fibonacci()
```

But this last line isn't an object with a method called fibonacci or actually it is?

Comment: Everything in python is an object - so, yes, a module is an object. But `fibonacci` is a function, not a method. (PS: note that you can import that function directly using `from Fibo import fibonacci`).

Comment: A method is just when a function is defined inside a class, so even the nomenclature being equal a 'object.method()' one, its not an method then?

Comment: No, it's simply an attribute of an object, which just happens to be a function, rather than static data. Methods always receive the instance as the first argument (usually called `self`, for instance-methods, or `cls`, for class-methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in Python is an object. If you're importing an object from a module, you will have the object in your current/actual module (i.e. program). You can create different namespaces and make your code more organized by using different files for your Python code. That's the advantage of using other modules and importing from it.

According to the Python documentation, it is better to simply avoid calling `fibonacci` a *method* and say that it is an *attribute* of an *object*, see:

**[method](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method)**

> A function which is defined inside a class body. [...]

**[attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-attribute)**

> A value associated with an object which is referenced by name using dotted expressions. For example, if an object o has an attribute a it would be referenced as o.a.

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation you can find the answer.

It boils down to this: 
"When a module is first imported, Python searches for the module and if found, it creates a module object 1, initializing it."

So basically, yes, Fibo is an object.

Comment: The question isn't whether the module is an object, but whether its member functions are methods.